# Changing the value of a joystick's Y axis

Tags: autohotkey

I'm currently trying to change the value of my joystick's (T.16000M) Y axis using AutoHotKey.

A little background first: I'm configuring some voice commands for [Star Citizen](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/), and I'm trying to write a script that would activate decoupled mode (so that I have 6 degrees of freedom), after which I would potentially adjust my ship's pitch by a full 180 degrees along the Y axis. I've discovered that I can't exactly do this using [VoiceAttack](http://www.voiceattack.com/) alone, because within the game, only raw mouse input is accepted, and I cannot figure out how to simulate raw mouse input with either VoiceAttack or AutoHotKey.

Therefore, my next best solution would be to change the value of my joystick's Y axis, if this is at all possible in AutoHotKey. I've done tons of googling, and I've searched the entire documentation for any clue on how to achieve my goal.

I understand that JoyX, JoyY, JoyZ, etc., can be used to map joystick input to some other sort of control, like in this [script that maps joystick input to the mouse cursor](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickMouse.htm).

I hope this post is appropriate for StackOverflow; I wasn't exactly sure where else to put it. Maybe superuser?

Anyway, thanks for your help.

By the way, here is the code I was planning to use for the mouse:

```
MouseMove, 0, 500, 10, R
MouseMove, 0, -500, 10, R
```

This works in Windows, but not in the game, because the game only accepts raw mouse input.

Comment: Does `#InstallMouseHook` help?

Comment: I'll try it out when I get home from work.

Comment: Please post more of your script. Is `MouseMove` triggered by a hotkey? If so, does the hotkey fail to trigger or does the window not receive the `MouseMove`? Since I suspect that the mouse hook won't help here, first play around with variations `SendMode`. Second, you could combine this with different settings for `SendLevel`. Not sure if `SendLevel` can be helpful, though.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate raw mouse movement with AutoHotkey, use `DllCall("mouse_event"...` (Google it, there are tons of examples).
To get VoiceAttack-like functionality in AHK, see [HotVoice](https://github.com/evilC/HotVoice)
It is absolutely impossible to alter a joystick in AHK like you can alter keyboard. You need to create an extra virtual joystick and send output to that. See [CvJoyInterface](https://github.com/evilC/AHK-CvJoyInterface).